# Understanding limit of a function in another article

Tags: limits

I am trying to understand an article mentioned here https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_3_2_delta_function.php. Some where down the explanation there's a statement marked (4.9) and it says

$u(x) = \lim\limits_{\alpha \to 0} u_\alpha(x)$ , $\alpha > 0$

Where $u(x)$ is defined to be a step function

\begin{equation}
     \hspace{50pt}
              u(x) = \left\{
              \begin{array}{l l}
                1  &  \quad  x \geq 0 \\
                0 &  \quad \text{otherwise}
              \end{array}\right\}
     \hspace{50pt}
            \end{equation}
And $u_\alpha(x)$ is defined to be as below
\begin{equation}
             \nonumber u_{\alpha}(x) = \left\{
              \begin{array}{l l}
                1  &  \quad   x > \frac{\alpha}{2} \\
                \frac{1}{\alpha} (x+\frac{\alpha}{2})  &   \quad  -\frac{\alpha}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{\alpha}{2} \\
                0 &  \quad x < -\frac{\alpha}{2}
              \end{array} \right\}
            \end{equation}
I tried taking the limit of $u_\alpha(x)$ as $\alpha$ approaches zero but i am not able to arrive at this statement $u(x) = \lim\limits_{\alpha \to 0} u_\alpha(x)$

Shouldnt the limit of $\lim\limits_{\alpha \to 0}  \frac{1}{\alpha} (x+\frac{\alpha}{2})$ when $-\frac{\alpha}{2} \leq x \leq \frac{\alpha}{2} $ be equal to $\infty$ ?.

Comment: If $0<\alpha < x/2$, then $u_{\alpha}(x)=1$.

Comment: First observe that as $\alpha \to 0,$ the interval you're interested in shrinks to the point $x=0.$ That might be significant. But perhaps they made some other assumption you've not spotted. Meh.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that as $\alpha \to 0,$ the interval $[-\alpha/2,\alpha/2]$ shrinks to the point $\{0\},$ and $(-\infty, -\alpha/2)\cup (\alpha/2,+\infty)$ goes to $(-\infty,+\infty),$ so that the result follows immediately.